# Product of pointwise sequences

Tags: real-analysis

- $(f_n)$ converges pointwise to $f$ on $A$
- $(g_n)$ converges pointwise to $g$ on $A$

Prove $(f_n g_n)$ converges pointwise to $fg$.

I am using the identity: $f_n g_n - fg = (f_n - f)(g_n - g) + f(g_n - g) + g(f_n - f)$.

\begin{align*}
 |f_ng_n - fg| &= |(f_n - f)(g_n - g) + f(g_n - g) + g(f_n - f)| \\
&\leq |(f_n - f)(g_n - g)| + |f(g_n - g)| + |g(f_n - f)|
\end{align*}

but I don't know where to go from here. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: This really shouldn't require work... You should already be familiar with this statement:  let $u_n$ and $v_n$ be two sequences of real numbers that converge respectively to $u$ and $v$, then $u_n v_n$ converges to $uv$.

Comment: $(f_n)$ and $(g_n)$ are sequences of functions

Comment: @DDRM but if you see pointwise convergence,  (f_ng_n) (x) is a numerical sequence

Comment: @wnitram I see. That makes sense. Then the conclusion would follow immediately by the Algebraic Limit Theorem for Sequences. I guess my work above could be used for proving uniform convergence. I believe $f_n$ and $g_n$ would have to be bounded though. Thanks for the clarification.